Is there a way to sample the boundary of the union of spheres? Without rejection
Suppose a shape is constructed from a union of spheres, $\bigcup_{i} S_i$ where $S_i$ are spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Is it possible to efficiently uniformly sample the boundary of this shape without rejection sampling?

What do you mean by the boundary of this shape (call it $S$)? If there are two unit spheres, whose centers are separated by one unit, is the boundary the entire union of the two spheres, or is it just the portion of the union that is further from the midway point than distance $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$?

Anyway, if the boundary is the entire union, then one can simply choose the individual sphere with probability proportional to the sphere's surface area, and then use a three-dimensional Gaussian, normalized, to select a point on that sphere's surface. If you only want "the outside" of the union (points that are not in the interior of any sphere), I suspect that only rejection sampling will do the trick in general.

@BrianTung The boundary as in $\delta S$. It is the set of points lying on the surface of a sphere (and not inside of any sphere) so yes the second guess. But my question asks precisely without rejection sampling

Hmm yes, I'm not optimistic about that, but I'll give it some thought.
